# GridLayout Android

Tags: android, layout

I am currently working on an Android App and it seems that when I use the GridLayout and put my tablet in landscape mode, the layout is reloaded and I lose all my variables.

Is there something special with this layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No its nothing special. It is how android system works.
However if you want to stop loading your activity every time configuration changes, you can put this code in your `Manifest.xml` file.

```
<activity>
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    ...
</activity>
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

Also note that this will stop recreating your activity each time orientation or screen size change.

That might not be an appropriate solution for each situation.

You can use `onConfigurationChanged()` method. This method of android tracks the change in configuration while your `activity` is running. This method is called by system. If you want your activity to show different layouts for both landscape and portrait mode, then simply create two `xml layouts` and put below code inside `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`:

```
@override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_landscape);
    else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_portrait);
}
```

Comment: You said one solution instead of stating the reasons anb other solutions. This might work but the OP may not understood the reason of using your code. Also it is recommended to add screenSize in configuration changes from API level 3.1

Comment: @VividVervet you are right, I am learning how to answer on stackoverflow and I will note your suggestion and I will update my answer too. 
Thank you.

Comment: thats pretty awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

when your orientation changes, android system recreates the activity to load the changes in that particular orientation. either you can prevent reloading or you have redesign the layout for each orientation. for changing the layout you have to create separate layout files and you have to set it in onCreate

ex:

```
   if(orientation == LANDSCAPE){
      setContentView(R.layout.layout_landscape);
   }else{
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_portrait);
   }
```

or as I said you have to prevent recreating the activity. It is not a good option even though you can give a try. for that you have to set it in your manifest.

```
<activity
android:name="MainActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate an android device the current activity and everything in it is destroyed and the activity is created again. To keep the variables override the onSaveInstanceState (which is called right before an activity is destroyed) and store your variables.

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Then in your onCreate method add the following code which will check to see if there is data from from when the activity may have been destroyed. If there is it will put the data into the proper variables so you can continue using the activity as if nothing changed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    ...
}
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html